# how to keep named but 0-row tibbles in a list with list_rbind?

Tags: r, purrr

Let's say I have a list with named elements. The elements are tibbles.
I would like to convert the list into one single tibble.

purrr's `list_rbind` works, with the critical shortcoming (at least for my purpose) that it drops the
element which is a 0-row tibble (although it is a named element).

```r
library(tidyverse)

li <- list("a"=tibble(x=1), "b"=tibble(x=2), "c"=tibble(x=NULL))
li
#> $a
#> # A tibble: 1 × 1
#>       x
#>   <dbl>
#> 1     1
#> 
#> $b
#> # A tibble: 1 × 1
#>       x
#>   <dbl>
#> 1     2
#> 
#> $c
#> # A tibble: 0 × 0


li %>% purrr::list_rbind(., names_to="element_names")

#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   element_names     x
#>   <chr>         <dbl>
#> 1 a                 1
#> 2 b                 2
```

The outcome I am looking for would be

```
#>   element_names     x
#>   <chr>         <dbl>
#> 1 a                 1
#> 2 b                 2
#> 3 c                 NA (or NULL?)
```

Any help? Many thanks.

Comment: On a side note, it might be better to do `"c" = tibble(x = numeric())`, otherwise `tibble` does not recognize the column `x` for element `c`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `enframe()` and `unnest()`:

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)

enframe(li, name = "element_names")  |>
  unnest(value, keep_empty = TRUE)

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  element_names     x
  <chr>         <dbl>
1 a                 1
2 b                 2
3 c                NA
```

Comment: many thanks, all responses were very helpful and would merit to be correct answers, but this one seems to be in IMHO the most convenient one.

Answer (score 5):

You might give `dplyr::bind_rows` + `tidyr::complete` a try:

```r
> library(dplyr)
> library(tidyr)
> li = list("a" = tibble(x = 1), "b" = tibble(x = 2), "c" = tibble(x = NULL))
> bind_rows(li, .id = "element_names") |>
+   complete(element_names = names(li))
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  element_names     x
  <chr>         <dbl>
1 a                 1
2 b                 2
3 c                NA
```

For what it's worth, base R:

```r
> li = list("a" = data.frame(x = 1), "b" = data.frame(x = 2), "c" = data.frame(x = NULL))
> 
> lapply(li, \(i) if(nrow(i)) i else setNames(rbind(i, NA), "x")) |>
+   do.call(rbind, args = _) |>
+   transform(elment_names = names(li))
   x elment_names
a  1            a
b  2            b
c NA            c
```

Answer (score 3):

### You can conditionally `add_row()`s with `map()`

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

li <- list("a"=tibble(x=1), "b"=tibble(x=2), "c"=tibble(x=NULL))

li <- map(li, \(x){
  if(nrow(x) == 0){
    add_row(x)
  } else x
})

li %>% purrr::list_rbind(., names_to="element_names")
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   element_names     x
#>   <chr>         <dbl>
#> 1 a                 1
#> 2 b                 2
#> 3 c                NA
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

If you don't pass anything to the `...` arguments of `dplyr::add_row()`, every column is assigned the default value of `NA`. Thus we create a one-row data frame in which every value is missing, which we can append to the other data frames in the list with `list_rbind()`.

Comment: You can reverse your if-else like `map(li, \(x) { if(nrow(x)) x else add_row(x) })`, i.e. if you do it the other way round,  you can get rid of `== 0`.

Comment: That's true, but it seems like a large loss of readability for the sake of 4 characters

Answer (score 1):

My solution is fairly explicit, relying on a join.

```
library(tidyverse)

li <- list("a" = tibble(x = 1),
           "b" = tibble(x = 2), 
           "c" = tibble(x = NULL))
li

li2 <- list_rbind(li, names_to = "element_names")

(base_df <- enframe(names(li),
                   value = "element_names",
                   name = NULL))
left_join(
  x = base_df,
  y = li2,
  by = "element_names"
)
```

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  element_names     x
  <chr>         <dbl>
1 a                 1
2 b                 2
3 c                NA
```